# Angular2 Http PUT gives wrong RequestMethod

Tags: angular

I can't understand why I can't use http put in Angular2.

When I'm doing http post, it give the correct request method:

[image]

However, when I use http put: it give OPTIONS as the request method:

[image]

I meant what the heck is this?

Here is the method that I'm using for post:

```
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  var body = 'amount=' + 12;
  this.http.post(this.host + '/orders', body, options)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    resolve('success')
  });
```

Here is the method that I'm using for PUT.

```
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let body = 'amount=' + 12;
  this.http.put(this.host + '/orders/1', body, options)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    resolve('success')
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's because of CORS. It's not related to Angular2. In the case of your POST method, a simple method will be executed. In the case of PUT, you're in the case of a preflight one so an additional request (an OPTIONS one) will be involved under the hood by the browser. And it seems that you have 404 on this OPTIONS method.

As a reminder:

> **Simple requests**. This use case applies if we use HTTP GET, HEAD and POST methods. In the case of POST methods, only content types with the following values are supported: text/plain, application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data.
>
> **Preflighted requests**. When the "simple requests" use case doesn’t apply, a first request (with the HTTP OPTIONS method) is made to check what can be done in the context of cross-domain requests.

I think that these articles could interest you:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/
- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

Comment: But I tested in the update method with Postman, it works fine, also in my server, express, I have enabled all of these: res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'); res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

Comment: Yes, but with Postman, you are in a Chrome plugin so you can have fewer restrictions. That's great for the CORS headers on the server side. But it's not enough regarding CORS preflight requests. You should use the `cors` module in your express application: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight (globally or per request).